# How can I search through data to locate records without a specific value?

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

- Table One has Case_Id and Case_code columns.
- Table Two has Case_id and Date_closed columns.

The two tables can be joined on Case_Id.

In Table One there are numerous Case_Id's and each Case_id will have numerous Case_code's.

In Table Two each Case_id has either a date within the Date_closed column or a null value.

The issue:

So let's say for instance the case_code for a closed case is 001.  So all cases that have a date in the Date_closed column in Table Two should have Case_code 001 in Table One.

However Case_id 111 has numerous case_codes in Table One and a Date_closed in Table Two but does not have the Case_code 001.

I need to create a report containing all case_id's within the database that have a case_closed date but no case_code 001.

Can anyone offer a solution or guidance on how I can achieve this?

Some sample data:

[Image of Table One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGjMZ.png)
[Image of Table Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL1oy.)

I need the output to provide me with case_id's 111 and 113 as they both have date_closed dates but do not have case_code 001.

Many Thanks in advance and if you need more information or know of a similar question please let me know :)

Apologies if this a really simple issue, I'm still learning the ropes!

Comment: can you provide some `sample data` and `expected output` please..

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your `Case_code` may `varchar`/`nvarchar`:

```
SELECT o.[Case_Id] 
FROM One as o WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN Two as t WITH (NOLOCK)
ON o.[Case_Id]=t.[Case_Id]
WHERE Date_closed IS NOT NULL AND t.[Case_code]!='001'
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the reply. I tried your solution but it returns every row where the Case_code isn't 001 so I get results for case_id 110, 111, 112 and 113.

I only need results returned for 111 and 113.  If you have any other ideas, that would be awesome!

Comment: can you please post your sample table as text instead image.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for getting back to me.  Managed to resolve this in the end using the following:

```
WHERE date_closed IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT case_id
    FROM One AS OneCopy
    WHERE Case_code = '001'
        AND two.case_id = oneCopy.case_id
```

This now returns only one line per case_id where there is no relevant case closure code.